# Links on the activity tab in the user profile are not clickable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There is a list of recent activities of a user in their profile, with the new design most of the entries in that list are no longer clickable. They should be linked to each post, but something seems to be interfering with that now. A few seem to work, but for most just nothing happens when I try to follow the link.

This happens in the latest Chrome on Windows 7. It seems that sometimes the first time I hover over the link it is clickable, but not if I hover over it a second time.

Removing the 15px top padding on the `.comments` CSS rule seems to solve this problem for me without affecting the layout.

Comment: I'm not seeing any problems (Windows, Chrome).

Comment: I don't see any problems either (Windows 7, Firefox)

Comment: XP, Firefox, I see the same thing, if you align the cursor with the top of the letters, you get the hand, otherwise not.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate or see this issue.  Is your zoom in your browser 100%?

Comment: @SeanGallagher I observed it at three different Chrome installations at 100% zoom. I looked a bit more at it and it only seems to happen for comments, the comment text seems to catch the click that should go to the link.

Comment: Mac OS, firefox. Same problem.

Comment: @SeanGallagher I've found a change in the CSS that solves it for me, I added that to my bug report.

Answer (score 1):

this padding in comments has been changed for a build later today. Thanks.